# Was it a common practice to announce the fare on the cab door in the sixties?

Tags: the-producers

The door of a cab is shown in a scene in the movie [*The Producers* (1968)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063462/) where the fare is printed onto it. Was this a common practice in those years or does this cab belong to a special company etc?

[image: Red cab with message on driver's side: "Rates: 35¢ first 1/5 mile, 5¢ each additional 1/5 mile"]

Comment: Its not exactly uncommon even more recently https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fe/Miami_taxi_fare.jpg

Comment: @iandotkelly Is this the same in New York? I've just found [http://goo.gl/oaAt0D ] (this article) where I can see the fare being printed on cabs from fifties but the recent ones don't have it.

Comment: You can search search something like 'antique taxi cabs', you see a number of classic yellow NYC cabs with the fare written on the side.  Some of these look potentially cars from the 50's & 60's.

Comment: Pretty much all the taxis in my city do that.  Taxis are regulated according to city rules, so if a particular city requires that, they probably have to do it, both then and now.

Comment: The car appears to be a prop car, not a real taxi. Note the crude lettering

Answer (score 2):

This livery (with the rate appearing in stylised font on the door) appears to be a common feature of all makes of cab in New York as late as the 1970s, when the [standard fare card](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/USACab.JPG) was introduced.

This is a 'Gotham' cab, [circa 1945 from New York.](https://www.life.com/lifestyle/all-hail-new-york-taxis-gotham-cabs-and-cabbies-of-the-1940s/)

[image: BW photo of a cab bearing message on front passenger door: "Rates 20¢ 1st 1/4 mile, 5¢ each addl. 1/4 mile"]

A 'Checker' cab from 1951

[image: BW photo of Checker cab with same message on driver's door, but without the word "Rates"]

and a 'Skyview Taxicab' from the late 1940s

[image: BW photo: Same message as other taxis but in light colored text on driver's door]